# How to find X number of matches in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
&123456/Some Data/741852
&654321/Some Data/963852
&987654/Some Data/325698
&123456/Some Data/789456
&321654/Some Data/789456
&987654/Some Data/471852
&123456/Some Data/987654
&987654/Some Data/845786
...
```

I'm looking for three or more matches to output into a file. The desired output is below:

`File1.txt`:

```
&123456/Some Data/741852
&123456/Some Data/789456
&123456/Some Data/987654
```

`File2.txt`:

```
&987654/Some Data/325698
&987654/Some Data/471852
&987654/Some Data/845786
```

Below is a function that I have tried to find the count but haven't quite figured out how to output to files:

```
function GetUserCounts($fileName) {
    $userCounts = @{}
    switch -regex -file $fileName {
        '&([0-9]{6})+' {
            $userName = $matches[1]
            $userCounts[$userName] = [int]$userCounts[$userName] + 1
        }
    }
    $userCounts.GetEnumerator() | select Name, Value
}

GetUserCounts .\FinalTest.txt
```

Comment: Please do not bury relevant information in comments. [edit] your question if you need to expand it. This time I took the liberty to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for adding that information to my question. This is my first time on this forum. I will know for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` for grouping the results by a particular portion of the line:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' | Group-Object { ($_ -split '/')[0] }
```

then filter for groups with 3 or more matches:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Count -ge 3 }
```

and write each group to a file:

```
... | ForEach-Object { $i++; $_.Group | Set-Content "File$i.txt" }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $i=0
 import-csv C:\temp\campaigns.txt -Delimiter "/" -Header id, data, num | group id | % {$i++; $_.Group | export-csv "C:\temp\file$i.txt"  -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "/" }
```

Comment: treating the file as a CSV assumes that "some data" will not contain the delimiter character. Also, `Export-Csv` will not only add the header, but also double quotes around the exported values.